# Set image to object, after downloading with NSURLSession

Tags: ios, image, swift, nsurlsession

I have 7 car objects for each one i need to download the car image and set it to Car object.

Once the downloading is finish and i retreive the image in didFinishDownloadingToURL function, I have two choices : 1 . load image directly from temp file 2.move file to another location and save it in Directory (for ex).

The problem is that I dont't know how set this retreived image to corresponding object!!!
If i use the first option, how can i find good and corresponding object to set the image ??

Or if i use the seconde options : Save file to directory , How can i find the corresponding image file and set it to corresponding object ?

Actually I use NSURLSession to download images from differents urls.
For that, I have DownloadSessionDelegate who manage URLSession calbacks. here you can find my class:

```
typealias CompleteHandlerBlock = () -> ()
class DownloadSessionDelegate: NSObject, NSURLSessionDelegate, NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate {

var handlerQueue : [String : CompleteHandlerBlock]!

class var sharedInstance:DownloadSessionDelegate {

    struct Static {

        static var instance :DownloadSessionDelegate?
        static var token : dispatch_once_t = 0 ;
    }

    dispatch_once(&Static.token) {
        Static.instance = DownloadSessionDelegate();
        Static.instance!.handlerQueue = [String : CompleteHandlerBlock]();
    }

    return Static.instance!
}

// Session delegate
func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, didBecomeInvalidWithError error: NSError?) {
    println("session error: \(error?.localizedDescription).")
}

func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, didReceiveChallenge challenge: NSURLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: (NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition, NSURLCredential!) -> Void) {
    completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition.UseCredential, NSURLCredential(forTrust: challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust))
}

func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, downloadTask: NSURLSessionDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingToURL location: NSURL) {
    println("session \(session) has finished the download task \(downloadTask) of URL \(location).")

    var fileHandle:NSFileHandle = NSFileHandle(forReadingAtPath: location.path!)!
    var data:NSData = fileHandle.readDataToEndOfFile()
    var image:UIImage = UIImage(data: data)! }
```

I put also handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession int AppDelegate and everything is good.

I have one and only class : UIImageUtils, in which i have function calls DownloadImage. every different class calls this fuction tho download their images. here you find this function :

```
// Download image
static func downloadImageFromUrl(urlImage:NSString, writeToDevice: Bool, storeName:NSString, object:    AnyObject) {

    var configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.backgroundSessionConfiguration(SessionProperties.identifier);
    var backgroundSession = NSURLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: DownloadSessionDelegate.sharedInstance, delegateQueue: nil);
    var url = NSURLRequest(URL:  NSURL(string: ConfigurationManager.host + urlImage)!);
    var downloadTask = backgroundSession.downloadTaskWithRequest(url);
    downloadTask.resume();

}
```

Thanks alot for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of going to all the trouble of using the delegate. You can use a the completion block of the `downloadTaskWithRequest` method.
I have modified the downloadImageFromUrl function to take a block. This function can be called from your car object so that you will get the call back in that instance.

```
func downloadImageFromUrl(urlImage:NSString, writeToDevice: Bool, storeName:NSString, object: AnyObject, onfinished:(UIImage) -> ()) {

    var configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.backgroundSessionConfiguration(SessionProperties.identifier);
    var backgroundSession = NSURLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: DownloadSessionDelegate.sharedInstance, delegateQueue: nil);
    var url = NSURLRequest(URL:  NSURL(string: ConfigurationManager.host + urlImage)!);
    var downloadTask = backgroundSession.dataTaskWithRequest(url, completionHandler: {
        data,response,error in

        if error == nil
        {
            if let image = UIImage(data: data)
            {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in

                    onfinished(image)
                })
            }
        }

    })
    downloadTask.resume();

}
```

Inside the car class

```
class Car
{
    func downloadImage
    {
        YourDelegate.downloadImageFromUrl(self.imageUrl, writeToDevice: true, storeName: "store", object: nil, onfinished: { downloadedImage in
            self.image = downloadedImage
        })
    }
}
```